# Spring cloud config server ssh to bitbucket problem

Tags: java, spring, ssl, bitbucket, egit

I'm trying to get the spring cloud config server connected to a bitbucket repo using ssh.  I've found lots of posts about the key needing to be rsa format.  I've confirmed I'm using the correct key format, and I have tried java versions 8, 15, and 17.

I can get it to work with a public repo, and a private repo using https with username/password.  But using a private key always gives me an exception for "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request"

```
2021-12-09 20:50:02.736  WARN 8 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.EnvironmentController        : Error getting the Environment with name=feedback profiles=development label=null includeOrigin=false

org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException: Cannot clone or checkout repository: git@bitbucket.org:jimjudd/service-config.git
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:320) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:262) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOneFromCandidate(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:188) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:132) [spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:109) [spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) [spring-core-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485) [spring-cloud-context-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92f4d81c.defaultLabel(<generated>) [spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:jimjudd/service-config.git: failed to send channel request
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:224) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:303) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:178) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:658) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:633) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:616) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:296) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:jimjudd/service-config.git: failed to send channel request
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.<init>(JschSession.java:167) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession.exec(JschSession.java:77) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:289) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:153) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:142) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:94) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1309) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:213) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestEnv.request(RequestEnv.java:52) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSession.sendRequests(ChannelSession.java:222) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec.start(ChannelExec.java:41) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.<init>(JschSession.java:159) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar!/:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

The server config is pretty straight forward

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          timeout: 30
          uri: "git@bitbucket.org:xyz/abc.git"
#          skip-ssl-validation: true
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
#          strictHostKeyChecking: false
#          known-hosts-file: "./known_hosts"
          private-key: |
                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                        MIIJJgIBAAKCAgEAz8V286zbc5nZ0Z+NTq5JcC2Fx2XNGKee4Lg/NIqa8KUCURMC
                        .
                        .
                        .    
                        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Haven't been able to get the right combination right.  Anyone know of anything else I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to insert `ssh:\\` at the front of your URL making it `uri: ssh://git@bitbucket.org:xyz/abc.git`

Comment: Ya I tried that, but it the config server doesn't like that.  I get a different error about a bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got something working.  Its not with ssh but with https, bit bucket allows you to generate a token and use that in the password field instead of the password to authenticate.  That will have to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that able to start Config Server, using Bitbucket with spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and spring-cloud Greenwich.SR2, on Win11

However, with spring-boot 2.6.3 and spring-cloud 2021.0.1, it is unable to access Bitbucket and throws the error message.

Here is my example that works:

```
#Work on spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and spring-cloud Greenwich.SR2

spring.application.name=Config Server
server.port=8030

spring.cloud.config.profile=default
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings=true

#Github, using link on Browser address and username/password(token)
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/yourUserName/SpringCloudConfigRepo
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=yourUserName
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=Token. Not password

#Bitbucket, using SSH URI and RSA key
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@bitbucket.org:yourUserName/springcloudconfigrepo.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key= \
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
line 1\n\
line n\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration below worked for me. I used HTTPS with auth token instead of SSH.

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/repo`enter code here`.git
          username: your_username
          password: your_login_token_not_password
          deleteUntrackedBranches: true
          refreshRate: 20
          search-paths: src/main/resources/configs/*
          clone-on-start: true
          basedir: /data/apps/git-configs-repo
          timeout: 30
          forcePull: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue with
[git protocol switch](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jgit/releases/5.11.0) from V1 to V2 in JGIT

You can change it back to V1 with following setting

```
git config --global protocol.version 1
```